# How to locate right anchor point location while making infinite zoom effect GIF?

Tags: after-effects, animation, zoom

I need to make something like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WzWyaTVQ7ELy2ZQj0J2SatQeVcMehF-W) in After Effects. Now, it would have been easy if the zoom effect origin was in the center, but I need it on some other point, so the borders of the **billboard** (see my screenshots) keeps snapping to composition, **and I can duplicate layer multiple times** to create a never ending effect.

Since I can't find the perfect anchor point location, when I duplicate layer, the two doesn't seem smooth when ***intersection*** happens. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbsGs.gif), you will understand.

My question is, do I need to do some hit and trials to find the correct location of desired anchor point?

Now, another problem I faced in scale effect is [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EtQgyh7TSCPbQ5AVFz1zadD1nlkK_KOz). The scale speed decreases, I don't know why, with time. This also makes someone notice that there's the ***intersection*** of multiple layers.

Here are some helpful screenshots:

[image]

Comment: I can't give you the entire solution, but here's an idea:
Your sequence seems to be the same format as the image. Create a simply Square Cross like this: X. Then put the X onto the frame. This should give you a pretty good estimate of where the point is

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. it looks like a solution. I'll try it. Any guess about speed issue?

Comment: Lo! It worked like a charm! The only issue is speed now.